# How to remove div tag dynamically from code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In mvc3, I want all views to be in "contener" div and use this in Layout.cshtml:

```
<div class="full_width"
    <div class="contener" >
       @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
```

But only index view must not be appear in "contener" div.
How to comment or hide or remove "contener" div with jscript or jquery-ajax, when only index view loading ? 
I cant show index view. because, it doesnt work in "contener" div. When index view loading, i want code to be so:

```
<div class="full_width" >
    *....its index view in "full_width" div, not in "contener" div....*
</div>
```

Comment: And try to make your question a little more clear, please. I don't see what you mean with "when only index.cshtml loading".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you.

```
<div class="full_width">
  @if (Request.RawUrl.StartsWith("/Index-or-whatever-your-url-is"))
  {
     @RenderBody()
  }
  else
  {
     <div class="contener">
        @RenderBody()
     </div>
  }
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
@{
        if (Request.RawUrl.Contains("Index")==false){
            <div class="contener" >
               @RenderBody()
            </div>
        }
     }
```